# App crashes when I want to get a website (using HtmlUnit)

Tags: android, html, runtime-error, htmlunit

For my app I want to get the html-text of a website. But the dynamic text on my website is written in JavaScript, so I wrote a Java-programm where I get the text using "HtmlUnit". Now I want to display this text in my android app. When I importet the newest version of HtmlUnit in Android-Studio an error occurred. I solved it by implementing an older version of HtmlUnit into the build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.12'
}
```

I also added "internet-permission" to the AndroidManifest.xml. Then I tried using HtmlUnit like in Java, but when I try to launch the app, it immediately crashes. The code of my "MainActivity.java" is the following:

```
package com.example.test.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        try {
            final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.google.com/");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Without `final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.google.com/");` the app starts perfectly without any errors. As soon as I add this code, the app doesn`t start properly and when I use the debugger, the following errors occur (I put it into "code-style" so it can be read better):

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.test.myapplication, PID: 8543
                  java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Superclass org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory of com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.SocksSocketFactory is declared final (declaration of 'com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.SocksSocketFactory' appears in /data/app/com.example.test.myapplication-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
                      at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.createWebConnection(WebClient.java:2123)
                      at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<init>(WebClient.java:129)
                      at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<init>(WebClient.java:182)
                      at com.example.test.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Do I have to change the HtmlUnit-code? I already tried it but the code is "readonly".
Or what can I do/use otherwise? (Maybe I have an error in my code?)

Thank you in advance!
Venatorc

Comment: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError is telling you  Superclass org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory of com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.SocksSocketFactory is declared final.

Why are you declaring HtmlPage page as final? Have you tried not to?

Comment: Yes I already tried it before, but the same error appears.